# Returns null value when using Localizations for multi-language system (Flutter, Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, delegates

I need to implement two languages in my application using packages (localizations).
In my application, there are 1 main view containing 4 tab views (`Home()`,`Graph()`,`History()`,`GoalSetting`), and 1 view(`Record()`) which are navigated by floating button.
My problem is, although `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.registeredWord` is correctly implemented at the main view and view from floating button, it returns "Null check operator used on a null value" at 4 tab views.
I am wondering how I can fix this.

Relating part of my code of main view is shown below.  If you need additional information, please let me know.

```
import 'package:bottom_navy_bar/bottom_navy_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() async {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('ja', ''),
        Locale('en', ''),
      ],
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
  );
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) :super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> viewList = [
    Home(), 
     const Graph(),
    History(),
    GoalSetting()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

home: Scaffold(
       
        body: viewList[_currentIndex],
        floatingActionButtonLocation: 

FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
            floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
                width: 60,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Record(),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                )),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
              selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
              showElevation: true,
              containerHeight: 70,
              itemCornerRadius: 24,
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
              items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
                BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.home), //OK
                  activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.show_chart),
                  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.graph), //OK
                  activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.history),
                  title: Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.history,
                  ),
                  activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.flag),
                  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.goals), //OK
                  activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Additionally, One example code of tab views is shown below.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:stylerecord/Model/goal.dart';

import 'Model/record.dart';
import 'Model/sqlite.dart';
import 'main.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WatchBoxBuilder(
        box: boxList[0],
        builder: (context, recordHiveBox) {
          return WatchBoxBuilder(
              box: boxList[1],
              builder: (context, goalHiveBox) {
                return Consumer<GoalData>( //The relevant error-causing widget
                  builder: (context, goalData, child) {
                    return Consumer<RecordData>(
                      builder: (context, recordData, child) {
                        RecordHive lastRecord =
                            recordHiveBox.getAt(recordHiveBox.length - 1);
                        return Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(
                              title: Text('StyleRecord'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
                          body: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'MPLUSRounded1c'),
                                    child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                         Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.part),  //Error("this was the stack")
                                          Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.weight),
```

........

```
                                          Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ankle),
                                          Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16))
                                        ])),
                                DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 25.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'MPLUSRounded1c'),
                                    child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          // Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                          //     .lasTime),
                                          Text(
                                              '${lastRecord.measurement[0]} kg'),
...
                                              Text(
                                                  '${lastRecord.measurement[8]} cm'),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20))
                                            ])),
                                    DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            fontFamily: 'MPLUSRounded1c'),
                                        child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: [
                                              // Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                              //     .toGoal),
                                              (goalHiveBox.isEmpty)
                                                  ? Text(
                                                  L10n.of(context)!
                                                          .noData)
                                                  : goalData.TextDif(
                                                      recordHiveBox.getAt(
                                                          recordHiveBox.length - 1),
                                                      goalHiveBox.getAt(0),
                                                      0),
...
                                              (goalHiveBox.isEmpty)
                                                  ? Text(
                                                  L10n.of(context)!
                                                          .noData)
                                                  : goalData.TextDif(
                                                      recordHiveBox.getAt(
                                                          recordHiveBox.length - 1),
                                                      goalHiveBox.getAt(0),
                                                      8),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16))
                                            ]))
                                  ]),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  });
            });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include code where you use AppLocalizations.of(context)!.registeredWord?

Comment: @EimantasG Thank you for your comment. I have added code of tab view. in both main view and tab view, I use  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.registeredWord. (title of BottomNavyBarItem in main title, and Text() in tab view.) It works in main view, but it does not work in tab view.

Comment: does your error message writes in what exact line the error was thrown?

Comment: @EimantasG Yes. I added where error occured with comments in code.

Comment: I solved! I don't understand actually, but I deleted one MaterialApp widget which are written two times in main(). Thank you very much for your thinking..!